# Angularjs passing values

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have input element like this

```
 <input type="text" name="a_id" ng-model="cont.a_id"  ui-event="{blur: 'blurCallback(a_id)'}"/>
```

in my controller I have

```
$scope.blurCallback = function (a_id) {
        $scope.aId = a_id;
        alert($scope.aId);
    }
```

When I run this alert gives me "undefined"
Please let me know what I am doing wrong that it wont pass the value when entered

Comment: Shouldn't it be `ui-event="{blur: 'blurCallback(\'a_id\')'}"`?

Comment: Have you tried making the call argument match the `ng-model`? `blurCallback(cont.a_id)`

Comment: Why not use the ng-blur event and do ng-blur="blurCallback(cont.a_id)"

Comment: What was the resolve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

'a_id' is undefined. you should pass 'cont.a_id'  as the argument to the function. check this plunk http://plnkr.co/edit/E6AJ4NFDJT3CtJXAzom1?p=preview