# How to pass value of textbox to a method in controller?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In Angularjs, I'm trying to pass a value from a textbox to method written in controller as below

### #Try 1

```
<input type="text" ng-blur="isExists(this.value)">
```

and within my controller I have

```
 $scope.isExists = function (theValue) {
    alert(theValue);
  };
```

It is not working.

### #Try 2

```
<input type="text" ng-model="username" ng-blur="isExists()">
```

and within controller

```
$scope.isExists = function () {
        alert($scope.username); // returns undefined
      };
```

How to pass value from `ng-blur` to a method within a Controller?

### Updates:

Any reason why the `value`is not seen in the textbox?

```
<input type="text" ng-model="username" ng-blur="isExists()">
```

[**Fiddle**](http://plnkr.co/edit/6MpvIni5cQeMeLCjbsqn?p=preview)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Angularjs passing values](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22673371/angularjs-passing-values).  Just know found this question in right side pane.   Please let me know if there is a better way.

Comment: You should use `$scope.$watch` for this.

Comment: there must be something wrong somewhere in your code the second metho should show the username value.

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/UP6s7kqXdGg8bSX6hZzd?p=previewtry 2 is working for me.

Comment: @sylwester seems weird, it is still gives me `undefined`.  Something must be bad with `$scope`I think so.  I tried to put `$scope` within console. But I don't find the `username` in it.

Comment: @Praveen I've added console.log($scope) to pluker and username exist and I've copy your code from here so I thing you've got some spell mistake http://plnkr.co/edit/UP6s7kqXdGg8bSX6hZzd?p=preview

Comment: try to add  $scope.username="John"; in your controller

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/ofAOa6kJA53o6eeQCkoR?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

Try2 should not return undefined if the `<input type="text"`

is filled with at least one character.

You can append {{ username }} on the html page just for debug purporses to make sure it was well binded.

Comment: As mentioned in this [comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24552209/how-to-pass-value-of-textbox-to-a-method-in-controller#comment38025428_24552209) seems weird but still the data binding works fine.

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="text" name="userId" id="txtid" />

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {

        $('#txtid').blur(function () {
            debugger;
            var id = $('#txtid').val();

            window.location = "/Home/CreateSupplier/?userid=" + id;

        });
    });
</script>
```

In controller

```
 public ActionResult CreateSupplier(string userid)
        {
            if (userid != null)
            {
                return Content("Received Username:" + userid);
            }
            return View(thesupplierList);
        }
```